# product of normal operators

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space.

> Let $A_1, A_2\in \mathcal{L}(E)$ be two normal operators. If $A_1A_2=A_2A_1$ then $A_1A_2$ and $A_2A_1$ are normal.
>   Why the converse is false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a two-dimensional counter-example. Take
$$
A=\pmatrix{ 0&1\\1&0}, \ B=\pmatrix{ 0&1\\-1&0},
$$
with $A$ symmetric, $B$ skew-symmetric, hence both normal. Their products
are symmetric
$$
AB=\pmatrix{-1&0\\0&1}, \ BA=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1},
$$
but $AB\ne BA$.